# Avr C code not working if main function adress after 0x200 on ATtiny25

Tags: raspberry-pi3, avr, avrdude, attiny

I am using a raspberry pi 3b running on Arch ARM to program an ATtiny25V. To do that, I use this modified version of avrdude : 
https://github.com/kcuzner/avrdude

First it worked great, but then I remarked that at some point, adding more code made the microcontroller not to work. (for example, if  Iput only a led switched on and loop forever in main, the led was not anymore lighted up).

I used `avr-objdump -S` to inspect the produced code, and I remarked that as long as the main function is located before `0x200`, then it seemed to work, and as soon as it is put further (because of growing code), nothing happened.

avrdude seems to flash faster with the image the triggers the bug (though it is bigger).

I have not found any similar problem on the internet, Thus if someone may have an idea of what could cause the problem ?

NOTE : the ATtiny25V has 2K flash memory, 128B eeprom, 128B SRAM

**EDIT 2 :**

I tried with the latest avrdude http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/avrdude/

with the patch of the `%ud` -> `%d`
http://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?47550

...But same behaviour

**EDIT 3 :**
I tried to relocate all function but main to another section put at 0x200 (so that the main is before)... But it does not work. So maybe the fail condition is any function put after 0x200

**EDIT :**
I tried with different ATtiny25V chips, but they all behave the same.

`avr-gcc -Wall -pedentic [...]` tells me no error nor warning
`avrdude` tells me all bytes have been verified. + the bytes number is < 2K.

```
avr-size -Ax working.elf
working.elf  :
section     size       addr
.text      0x210        0x0
.data        0x6   0x800060
.bss        0x11   0x800066
.comment    0x11        0x0
Total      0x238
```

```
avr-size -Ax fail.elf
fail.elf
section     size       addr
.text      0x2c2        0x0
.data        0x6   0x800060
.bss        0x11   0x800066
.comment    0x11        0x0
Total      0x2ea
```

`avr-objdump working.elf -S`

```
working.elf:     format de fichier elf32-avr


Déassemblage de la section .text :

00000000 <__do_copy_data>:
   0:   10 e0           ldi r17, 0x00   ; 0
   2:   a0 e6           ldi r26, 0x60   ; 96
   4:   b0 e0           ldi r27, 0x00   ; 0
   6:   e0 e1           ldi r30, 0x10   ; 16
   8:   f2 e0           ldi r31, 0x02   ; 2
   a:   03 c0           rjmp    .+6         ; 0x12 <__zero_reg__+0x11>
   c:   c8 95           lpm
   e:   31 96           adiw    r30, 0x01   ; 1
  10:   0d 92           st  X+, r0
  12:   a6 36           cpi r26, 0x66   ; 102
  14:   b1 07           cpc r27, r17
  16:   d1 f7           brne    .-12        ; 0xc <__zero_reg__+0xb>

00000018 <__do_clear_bss>:
  18:   20 e0           ldi r18, 0x00   ; 0
  1a:   a6 e6           ldi r26, 0x66   ; 102
  1c:   b0 e0           ldi r27, 0x00   ; 0
  1e:   01 c0           rjmp    .+2         ; 0x22 <.do_clear_bss_start>

00000020 <.do_clear_bss_loop>:
  20:   1d 92           st  X+, r1

00000022 <.do_clear_bss_start>:
  22:   a7 37           cpi r26, 0x77   ; 119
  24:   b2 07           cpc r27, r18
  26:   e1 f7           brne    .-8         ; 0x20 <.do_clear_bss_loop>

00000028 <nop>:
  28:   08 95           ret

0000002a <CmdResetTimer>:
  2a:   84 e1           ldi r24, 0x14   ; 20
  2c:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
  2e:   08 95           ret

00000030 <CmdEndEnableWD>:
  30:   80 91 73 00     lds r24, 0x0073 ; 0x800073 <cmdIn+0x3>
  34:   80 93 6b 00     sts 0x006B, r24 ; 0x80006b <wdEnabled>
  38:   08 95           ret

0000003a <CmdEnableWD>:
  3a:   80 91 6b 00     lds r24, 0x006B ; 0x80006b <wdEnabled>
  3e:   80 93 6f 00     sts 0x006F, r24 ; 0x80006f <cmdOut+0x3>
  42:   88 e1           ldi r24, 0x18   ; 24
  44:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
  46:   08 95           ret

00000048 <ledT>:
  48:   88 b3           in  r24, 0x18   ; 24
  4a:   90 e1           ldi r25, 0x10   ; 16
  4c:   89 27           eor r24, r25
  4e:   88 bb           out 0x18, r24   ; 24
  50:   08 95           ret

00000052 <led>:
  52:   88 23           and r24, r24
  54:   11 f0           breq    .+4         ; 0x5a <led+0x8>
  56:   c4 9a           sbi 0x18, 4 ; 24
  58:   08 95           ret
  5a:   c4 98           cbi 0x18, 4 ; 24
  5c:   08 95           ret

0000005e <dbugT>:
  5e:   88 b3           in  r24, 0x18   ; 24
  60:   98 e0           ldi r25, 0x08   ; 8
  62:   89 27           eor r24, r25
  64:   88 bb           out 0x18, r24   ; 24
  66:   08 95           ret

00000068 <dbug>:
  68:   88 23           and r24, r24
  6a:   11 f0           breq    .+4         ; 0x70 <dbug+0x8>
  6c:   c3 9a           sbi 0x18, 3 ; 24
  6e:   08 95           ret
  70:   c3 98           cbi 0x18, 3 ; 24
  72:   08 95           ret

00000074 <__vector_14>:
  74:   1f 92           push    r1
  76:   0f 92           push    r0
  78:   0f b6           in  r0, 0x3f    ; 63
  7a:   0f 92           push    r0
  7c:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  7e:   2f 93           push    r18
  80:   3f 93           push    r19
  82:   4f 93           push    r20
  84:   5f 93           push    r21
  86:   6f 93           push    r22
  88:   7f 93           push    r23
  8a:   8f 93           push    r24
  8c:   9f 93           push    r25
  8e:   af 93           push    r26
  90:   bf 93           push    r27
  92:   ef 93           push    r30
  94:   ff 93           push    r31
  96:   d8 df           rcall   .-80        ; 0x48 <ledT>
  98:   80 91 76 00     lds r24, 0x0076 ; 0x800076 <cmdState>
  9c:   83 30           cpi r24, 0x03   ; 3
  9e:   00 f5           brcc    .+64        ; 0xe0 <__vector_14+0x6c>
  a0:   88 23           and r24, r24
  a2:   99 f1           breq    .+102       ; 0x10a <__vector_14+0x96>
  a4:   20 91 74 00     lds r18, 0x0074 ; 0x800074 <cmdRemaining>
  a8:   84 e0           ldi r24, 0x04   ; 4
  aa:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
  ac:   fc 01           movw    r30, r24
  ae:   e2 1b           sub r30, r18
  b0:   f1 09           sbc r31, r1
  b2:   e4 59           subi    r30, 0x94   ; 148
  b4:   ff 4f           sbci    r31, 0xFF   ; 255
  b6:   20 81           ld  r18, Z
  b8:   2f b9           out 0x0f, r18   ; 15
  ba:   20 91 74 00     lds r18, 0x0074 ; 0x800074 <cmdRemaining>
  be:   30 b3           in  r19, 0x10   ; 16
  c0:   82 1b           sub r24, r18
  c2:   91 09           sbc r25, r1
  c4:   fc 01           movw    r30, r24
  c6:   e0 59           subi    r30, 0x90   ; 144
  c8:   ff 4f           sbci    r31, 0xFF   ; 255
  ca:   30 83           st  Z, r19
  cc:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
  ce:   82 0f           add r24, r18
  d0:   80 93 74 00     sts 0x0074, r24 ; 0x800074 <cmdRemaining>
  d4:   81 11           cpse    r24, r1
  d6:   06 c0           rjmp    .+12        ; 0xe4 <__vector_14+0x70>
  d8:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
  da:   8f b9           out 0x0f, r24   ; 15
  dc:   83 e0           ldi r24, 0x03   ; 3
  de:   19 c0           rjmp    .+50        ; 0x112 <__vector_14+0x9e>
  e0:   83 30           cpi r24, 0x03   ; 3
  e2:   d1 f0           breq    .+52        ; 0x118 <__vector_14+0xa4>
  e4:   80 e4           ldi r24, 0x40   ; 64
  e6:   8e b9           out 0x0e, r24   ; 14
  e8:   ff 91           pop r31
  ea:   ef 91           pop r30
  ec:   bf 91           pop r27
  ee:   af 91           pop r26
  f0:   9f 91           pop r25
  f2:   8f 91           pop r24
  f4:   7f 91           pop r23
  f6:   6f 91           pop r22
  f8:   5f 91           pop r21
  fa:   4f 91           pop r20
  fc:   3f 91           pop r19
  fe:   2f 91           pop r18
 100:   0f 90           pop r0
 102:   0f be           out 0x3f, r0    ; 63
 104:   0f 90           pop r0
 106:   1f 90           pop r1
 108:   18 95           reti
 10a:   80 b3           in  r24, 0x10   ; 16
 10c:   80 93 75 00     sts 0x0075, r24 ; 0x800075 <cmdReceived>
 110:   81 e0           ldi r24, 0x01   ; 1
 112:   80 93 76 00     sts 0x0076, r24 ; 0x800076 <cmdState>
 116:   e6 cf           rjmp    .-52        ; 0xe4 <__vector_14+0x70>
 118:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
 11a:   8f b9           out 0x0f, r24   ; 15
 11c:   e3 cf           rjmp    .-58        ; 0xe4 <__vector_14+0x70>

0000011e <start_blink>:
 11e:   80 91 66 00     lds r24, 0x0066 ; 0x800066 <__data_end>
 122:   8b 30           cpi r24, 0x0B   ; 11
 124:   29 f0           breq    .+10        ; 0x130 <start_blink+0x12>
 126:   8a 30           cpi r24, 0x0A   ; 10
 128:   21 f4           brne    .+8         ; 0x132 <start_blink+0x14>
 12a:   8b e0           ldi r24, 0x0B   ; 11
 12c:   80 93 66 00     sts 0x0066, r24 ; 0x800066 <__data_end>
 130:   08 95           ret
 132:   80 91 67 00     lds r24, 0x0067 ; 0x800067 <i>
 136:   90 91 68 00     lds r25, 0x0068 ; 0x800068 <i+0x1>
 13a:   a0 91 69 00     lds r26, 0x0069 ; 0x800069 <i+0x2>
 13e:   b0 91 6a 00     lds r27, 0x006A ; 0x80006a <i+0x3>
 142:   01 96           adiw    r24, 0x01   ; 1
 144:   a1 1d           adc r26, r1
 146:   b1 1d           adc r27, r1
 148:   80 93 67 00     sts 0x0067, r24 ; 0x800067 <i>
 14c:   90 93 68 00     sts 0x0068, r25 ; 0x800068 <i+0x1>
 150:   a0 93 69 00     sts 0x0069, r26 ; 0x800069 <i+0x2>
 154:   b0 93 6a 00     sts 0x006A, r27 ; 0x80006a <i+0x3>
 158:   88 34           cpi r24, 0x48   ; 72
 15a:   9c 40           sbci    r25, 0x0C   ; 12
 15c:   a1 05           cpc r26, r1
 15e:   b1 05           cpc r27, r1
 160:   09 f4           brne    .+2         ; 0x164 <start_blink+0x46>
 162:   c4 9a           sbi 0x18, 4 ; 24
 164:   80 91 67 00     lds r24, 0x0067 ; 0x800067 <i>
 168:   90 91 68 00     lds r25, 0x0068 ; 0x800068 <i+0x1>
 16c:   a0 91 69 00     lds r26, 0x0069 ; 0x800069 <i+0x2>
 170:   b0 91 6a 00     lds r27, 0x006A ; 0x80006a <i+0x3>
 174:   81 15           cp  r24, r1
 176:   98 41           sbci    r25, 0x18   ; 24
 178:   a1 05           cpc r26, r1
 17a:   b1 05           cpc r27, r1
 17c:   c8 f2           brcs    .-78        ; 0x130 <start_blink+0x12>
 17e:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
 180:   68 df           rcall   .-304       ; 0x52 <led>
 182:   10 92 67 00     sts 0x0067, r1  ; 0x800067 <i>
 186:   10 92 68 00     sts 0x0068, r1  ; 0x800068 <i+0x1>
 18a:   10 92 69 00     sts 0x0069, r1  ; 0x800069 <i+0x2>
 18e:   10 92 6a 00     sts 0x006A, r1  ; 0x80006a <i+0x3>
 192:   80 91 66 00     lds r24, 0x0066 ; 0x800066 <__data_end>
 196:   8f 5f           subi    r24, 0xFF   ; 255
 198:   c9 cf           rjmp    .-110       ; 0x12c <start_blink+0xe>

0000019a <handleCmd>:
 19a:   80 91 76 00     lds r24, 0x0076 ; 0x800076 <cmdState>
 19e:   81 30           cpi r24, 0x01   ; 1
 1a0:   31 f5           brne    .+76        ; 0x1ee <handleCmd+0x54>
 1a2:   e0 91 75 00     lds r30, 0x0075 ; 0x800075 <cmdReceived>
 1a6:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
 1a8:   ee 0f           add r30, r30
 1aa:   ff 1f           adc r31, r31
 1ac:   ee 59           subi    r30, 0x9E   ; 158
 1ae:   ff 4f           sbci    r31, 0xFF   ; 255
 1b0:   01 90           ld  r0, Z+
 1b2:   f0 81           ld  r31, Z
 1b4:   e0 2d           mov r30, r0
 1b6:   09 95           icall
 1b8:   90 93 61 00     sts 0x0061, r25 ; 0x800061 <__data_start+0x1>
 1bc:   80 93 60 00     sts 0x0060, r24 ; 0x800060 <__data_start>
 1c0:   80 91 74 00     lds r24, 0x0074 ; 0x800074 <cmdRemaining>
 1c4:   81 11           cpse    r24, r1
 1c6:   0f c0           rjmp    .+30        ; 0x1e6 <handleCmd+0x4c>
 1c8:   83 e0           ldi r24, 0x03   ; 3
 1ca:   80 93 76 00     sts 0x0076, r24 ; 0x800076 <cmdState>
 1ce:   e0 91 60 00     lds r30, 0x0060 ; 0x800060 <__data_start>
 1d2:   f0 91 61 00     lds r31, 0x0061 ; 0x800061 <__data_start+0x1>
 1d6:   09 95           icall
 1d8:   84 e1           ldi r24, 0x14   ; 20
 1da:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
 1dc:   90 93 61 00     sts 0x0061, r25 ; 0x800061 <__data_start+0x1>
 1e0:   80 93 60 00     sts 0x0060, r24 ; 0x800060 <__data_start>
 1e4:   06 c0           rjmp    .+12        ; 0x1f2 <handleCmd+0x58>
 1e6:   82 e0           ldi r24, 0x02   ; 2
 1e8:   80 93 76 00     sts 0x0076, r24 ; 0x800076 <cmdState>
 1ec:   08 95           ret
 1ee:   83 30           cpi r24, 0x03   ; 3
 1f0:   71 f3           breq    .-36        ; 0x1ce <handleCmd+0x34>
 1f2:   08 95           ret

000001f4 <main>:
 1f4:   18 ba           out 0x18, r1    ; 24
 1f6:   8a e1           ldi r24, 0x1A   ; 26
 1f8:   87 bb           out 0x17, r24   ; 23
 1fa:   88 e5           ldi r24, 0x58   ; 88
 1fc:   8d b9           out 0x0d, r24   ; 13
 1fe:   80 e4           ldi r24, 0x40   ; 64
 200:   8e b9           out 0x0e, r24   ; 14
 202:   85 e2           ldi r24, 0x25   ; 37
 204:   8f b9           out 0x0f, r24   ; 15
 206:   78 94           sei
 208:   c4 9a           sbi 0x18, 4 ; 24
 20a:   c7 df           rcall   .-114       ; 0x19a <handleCmd>
 20c:   88 df           rcall   .-240       ; 0x11e <start_blink>
 20e:   fd cf           rjmp    .-6         ; 0x20a <main+0x16>
```

`avr-objdump failing.elf`

```
Watchdog.elf:     format de fichier elf32-avr


Déassemblage de la section .text :

00000000 <__do_copy_data>:
   0:   10 e0           ldi r17, 0x00   ; 0
   2:   a0 e6           ldi r26, 0x60   ; 96
   4:   b0 e0           ldi r27, 0x00   ; 0
   6:   e2 ec           ldi r30, 0xC2   ; 194
   8:   f2 e0           ldi r31, 0x02   ; 2
   a:   03 c0           rjmp    .+6         ; 0x12 <__zero_reg__+0x11>
   c:   c8 95           lpm
   e:   31 96           adiw    r30, 0x01   ; 1
  10:   0d 92           st  X+, r0
  12:   a6 36           cpi r26, 0x66   ; 102
  14:   b1 07           cpc r27, r17
  16:   d1 f7           brne    .-12        ; 0xc <__zero_reg__+0xb>

00000018 <__do_clear_bss>:
  18:   20 e0           ldi r18, 0x00   ; 0
  1a:   a6 e6           ldi r26, 0x66   ; 102
  1c:   b0 e0           ldi r27, 0x00   ; 0
  1e:   01 c0           rjmp    .+2         ; 0x22 <.do_clear_bss_start>

00000020 <.do_clear_bss_loop>:
  20:   1d 92           st  X+, r1

00000022 <.do_clear_bss_start>:
  22:   a7 37           cpi r26, 0x77   ; 119
  24:   b2 07           cpc r27, r18
  26:   e1 f7           brne    .-8         ; 0x20 <.do_clear_bss_loop>

00000028 <nop>:
  28:   08 95           ret

0000002a <CmdResetTimer>:
  2a:   84 e1           ldi r24, 0x14   ; 20
  2c:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
  2e:   08 95           ret

00000030 <CmdEndEnableWD>:
  30:   80 91 73 00     lds r24, 0x0073 ; 0x800073 <cmdIn+0x3>
  34:   80 93 6b 00     sts 0x006B, r24 ; 0x80006b <wdEnabled>
  38:   08 95           ret

0000003a <CmdEnableWD>:
  3a:   80 91 6b 00     lds r24, 0x006B ; 0x80006b <wdEnabled>
  3e:   80 93 6f 00     sts 0x006F, r24 ; 0x80006f <cmdOut+0x3>
  42:   88 e1           ldi r24, 0x18   ; 24
  44:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
  46:   08 95           ret

00000048 <ledT>:
  48:   88 b3           in  r24, 0x18   ; 24
  4a:   90 e1           ldi r25, 0x10   ; 16
  4c:   89 27           eor r24, r25
  4e:   88 bb           out 0x18, r24   ; 24
  50:   08 95           ret

00000052 <led>:
  52:   88 23           and r24, r24
  54:   11 f0           breq    .+4         ; 0x5a <led+0x8>
  56:   c4 9a           sbi 0x18, 4 ; 24
  58:   08 95           ret
  5a:   c4 98           cbi 0x18, 4 ; 24
  5c:   08 95           ret

0000005e <dbugT>:
  5e:   88 b3           in  r24, 0x18   ; 24
  60:   98 e0           ldi r25, 0x08   ; 8
  62:   89 27           eor r24, r25
  64:   88 bb           out 0x18, r24   ; 24
  66:   08 95           ret

00000068 <dbug>:
  68:   88 23           and r24, r24
  6a:   11 f0           breq    .+4         ; 0x70 <dbug+0x8>
  6c:   c3 9a           sbi 0x18, 3 ; 24
  6e:   08 95           ret
  70:   c3 98           cbi 0x18, 3 ; 24
  72:   08 95           ret

00000074 <__vector_14>:
  74:   1f 92           push    r1
  76:   0f 92           push    r0
  78:   0f b6           in  r0, 0x3f    ; 63
  7a:   0f 92           push    r0
  7c:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  7e:   2f 93           push    r18
  80:   3f 93           push    r19
  82:   4f 93           push    r20
  84:   5f 93           push    r21
  86:   6f 93           push    r22
  88:   7f 93           push    r23
  8a:   8f 93           push    r24
  8c:   9f 93           push    r25
  8e:   af 93           push    r26
  90:   bf 93           push    r27
  92:   ef 93           push    r30
  94:   ff 93           push    r31
  96:   d8 df           rcall   .-80        ; 0x48 <ledT>
  98:   80 91 76 00     lds r24, 0x0076 ; 0x800076 <cmdState>
  9c:   83 30           cpi r24, 0x03   ; 3
  9e:   00 f5           brcc    .+64        ; 0xe0 <__vector_14+0x6c>
  a0:   88 23           and r24, r24
  a2:   99 f1           breq    .+102       ; 0x10a <__vector_14+0x96>
  a4:   20 91 74 00     lds r18, 0x0074 ; 0x800074 <cmdRemaining>
  a8:   84 e0           ldi r24, 0x04   ; 4
  aa:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
  ac:   fc 01           movw    r30, r24
  ae:   e2 1b           sub r30, r18
  b0:   f1 09           sbc r31, r1
  b2:   e4 59           subi    r30, 0x94   ; 148
  b4:   ff 4f           sbci    r31, 0xFF   ; 255
  b6:   20 81           ld  r18, Z
  b8:   2f b9           out 0x0f, r18   ; 15
  ba:   20 91 74 00     lds r18, 0x0074 ; 0x800074 <cmdRemaining>
  be:   30 b3           in  r19, 0x10   ; 16
  c0:   82 1b           sub r24, r18
  c2:   91 09           sbc r25, r1
  c4:   fc 01           movw    r30, r24
  c6:   e0 59           subi    r30, 0x90   ; 144
  c8:   ff 4f           sbci    r31, 0xFF   ; 255
  ca:   30 83           st  Z, r19
  cc:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
  ce:   82 0f           add r24, r18
  d0:   80 93 74 00     sts 0x0074, r24 ; 0x800074 <cmdRemaining>
  d4:   81 11           cpse    r24, r1
  d6:   06 c0           rjmp    .+12        ; 0xe4 <__vector_14+0x70>
  d8:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
  da:   8f b9           out 0x0f, r24   ; 15
  dc:   83 e0           ldi r24, 0x03   ; 3
  de:   19 c0           rjmp    .+50        ; 0x112 <__vector_14+0x9e>
  e0:   83 30           cpi r24, 0x03   ; 3
  e2:   d1 f0           breq    .+52        ; 0x118 <__vector_14+0xa4>
  e4:   80 e4           ldi r24, 0x40   ; 64
  e6:   8e b9           out 0x0e, r24   ; 14
  e8:   ff 91           pop r31
  ea:   ef 91           pop r30
  ec:   bf 91           pop r27
  ee:   af 91           pop r26
  f0:   9f 91           pop r25
  f2:   8f 91           pop r24
  f4:   7f 91           pop r23
  f6:   6f 91           pop r22
  f8:   5f 91           pop r21
  fa:   4f 91           pop r20
  fc:   3f 91           pop r19
  fe:   2f 91           pop r18
 100:   0f 90           pop r0
 102:   0f be           out 0x3f, r0    ; 63
 104:   0f 90           pop r0
 106:   1f 90           pop r1
 108:   18 95           reti
 10a:   80 b3           in  r24, 0x10   ; 16
 10c:   80 93 75 00     sts 0x0075, r24 ; 0x800075 <cmdReceived>
 110:   81 e0           ldi r24, 0x01   ; 1
 112:   80 93 76 00     sts 0x0076, r24 ; 0x800076 <cmdState>
 116:   e6 cf           rjmp    .-52        ; 0xe4 <__vector_14+0x70>
 118:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
 11a:   8f b9           out 0x0f, r24   ; 15
 11c:   e3 cf           rjmp    .-58        ; 0xe4 <__vector_14+0x70>

0000011e <debug>:
 11e:   ef 92           push    r14
 120:   ff 92           push    r15
 122:   0f 93           push    r16
 124:   1f 93           push    r17
 126:   cf 93           push    r28
 128:   df 93           push    r29
 12a:   ec 01           movw    r28, r24
 12c:   16 2f           mov r17, r22
 12e:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
 130:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
 132:   c3 9a           sbi 0x18, 3 ; 24
 134:   01 96           adiw    r24, 0x01   ; 1
 136:   81 15           cp  r24, r1
 138:   24 e0           ldi r18, 0x04   ; 4
 13a:   92 07           cpc r25, r18
 13c:   d1 f7           brne    .-12        ; 0x132 <debug+0x14>
 13e:   f1 2c           mov r15, r1
 140:   e1 2c           mov r14, r1
 142:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
 144:   91 df           rcall   .-222       ; 0x68 <dbug>
 146:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
 148:   e8 1a           sub r14, r24
 14a:   f8 0a           sbc r15, r24
 14c:   e1 14           cp  r14, r1
 14e:   24 e0           ldi r18, 0x04   ; 4
 150:   f2 06           cpc r15, r18
 152:   b9 f7           brne    .-18        ; 0x142 <debug+0x24>
 154:   11 11           cpse    r17, r1
 156:   07 c0           rjmp    .+14        ; 0x166 <debug+0x48>
 158:   df 91           pop r29
 15a:   cf 91           pop r28
 15c:   1f 91           pop r17
 15e:   0f 91           pop r16
 160:   ff 90           pop r15
 162:   ef 90           pop r14
 164:   08 95           ret
 166:   08 e0           ldi r16, 0x08   ; 8
 168:   f1 2c           mov r15, r1
 16a:   e1 2c           mov r14, r1
 16c:   88 81           ld  r24, Y
 16e:   88 1f           adc r24, r24
 170:   88 27           eor r24, r24
 172:   88 1f           adc r24, r24
 174:   79 df           rcall   .-270       ; 0x68 <dbug>
 176:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
 178:   e8 1a           sub r14, r24
 17a:   f8 0a           sbc r15, r24
 17c:   e1 14           cp  r14, r1
 17e:   24 e1           ldi r18, 0x14   ; 20
 180:   f2 06           cpc r15, r18
 182:   a1 f7           brne    .-24        ; 0x16c <debug+0x4e>
 184:   88 81           ld  r24, Y
 186:   88 0f           add r24, r24
 188:   88 83           st  Y, r24
 18a:   f1 2c           mov r15, r1
 18c:   e1 2c           mov r14, r1
 18e:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
 190:   6b df           rcall   .-298       ; 0x68 <dbug>
 192:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
 194:   e8 1a           sub r14, r24
 196:   f8 0a           sbc r15, r24
 198:   e1 14           cp  r14, r1
 19a:   24 e0           ldi r18, 0x04   ; 4
 19c:   f2 06           cpc r15, r18
 19e:   b9 f7           brne    .-18        ; 0x18e <debug+0x70>
 1a0:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
 1a2:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
 1a4:   c3 9a           sbi 0x18, 3 ; 24
 1a6:   01 96           adiw    r24, 0x01   ; 1
 1a8:   81 15           cp  r24, r1
 1aa:   24 e0           ldi r18, 0x04   ; 4
 1ac:   92 07           cpc r25, r18
 1ae:   d1 f7           brne    .-12        ; 0x1a4 <debug+0x86>
 1b0:   f1 2c           mov r15, r1
 1b2:   e1 2c           mov r14, r1
 1b4:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
 1b6:   58 df           rcall   .-336       ; 0x68 <dbug>
 1b8:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
 1ba:   e8 1a           sub r14, r24
 1bc:   f8 0a           sbc r15, r24
 1be:   e1 14           cp  r14, r1
 1c0:   24 e0           ldi r18, 0x04   ; 4
 1c2:   f2 06           cpc r15, r18
 1c4:   b9 f7           brne    .-18        ; 0x1b4 <debug+0x96>
 1c6:   01 50           subi    r16, 0x01   ; 1
 1c8:   79 f6           brne    .-98        ; 0x168 <debug+0x4a>
 1ca:   21 96           adiw    r28, 0x01   ; 1
 1cc:   11 50           subi    r17, 0x01   ; 1
 1ce:   c2 cf           rjmp    .-124       ; 0x154 <debug+0x36>

000001d0 <start_blink>:
 1d0:   80 91 66 00     lds r24, 0x0066 ; 0x800066 <__data_end>
 1d4:   8b 30           cpi r24, 0x0B   ; 11
 1d6:   29 f0           breq    .+10        ; 0x1e2 <start_blink+0x12>
 1d8:   8a 30           cpi r24, 0x0A   ; 10
 1da:   21 f4           brne    .+8         ; 0x1e4 <start_blink+0x14>
 1dc:   8b e0           ldi r24, 0x0B   ; 11
 1de:   80 93 66 00     sts 0x0066, r24 ; 0x800066 <__data_end>
 1e2:   08 95           ret
 1e4:   80 91 67 00     lds r24, 0x0067 ; 0x800067 <i>
 1e8:   90 91 68 00     lds r25, 0x0068 ; 0x800068 <i+0x1>
 1ec:   a0 91 69 00     lds r26, 0x0069 ; 0x800069 <i+0x2>
 1f0:   b0 91 6a 00     lds r27, 0x006A ; 0x80006a <i+0x3>
 1f4:   01 96           adiw    r24, 0x01   ; 1
 1f6:   a1 1d           adc r26, r1
 1f8:   b1 1d           adc r27, r1
 1fa:   80 93 67 00     sts 0x0067, r24 ; 0x800067 <i>
 1fe:   90 93 68 00     sts 0x0068, r25 ; 0x800068 <i+0x1>
 202:   a0 93 69 00     sts 0x0069, r26 ; 0x800069 <i+0x2>
 206:   b0 93 6a 00     sts 0x006A, r27 ; 0x80006a <i+0x3>
 20a:   88 34           cpi r24, 0x48   ; 72
 20c:   9c 40           sbci    r25, 0x0C   ; 12
 20e:   a1 05           cpc r26, r1
 210:   b1 05           cpc r27, r1
 212:   09 f4           brne    .+2         ; 0x216 <start_blink+0x46>
 214:   c4 9a           sbi 0x18, 4 ; 24
 216:   80 91 67 00     lds r24, 0x0067 ; 0x800067 <i>
 21a:   90 91 68 00     lds r25, 0x0068 ; 0x800068 <i+0x1>
 21e:   a0 91 69 00     lds r26, 0x0069 ; 0x800069 <i+0x2>
 222:   b0 91 6a 00     lds r27, 0x006A ; 0x80006a <i+0x3>
 226:   81 15           cp  r24, r1
 228:   98 41           sbci    r25, 0x18   ; 24
 22a:   a1 05           cpc r26, r1
 22c:   b1 05           cpc r27, r1
 22e:   c8 f2           brcs    .-78        ; 0x1e2 <start_blink+0x12>
 230:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
 232:   0f df           rcall   .-482       ; 0x52 <led>
 234:   10 92 67 00     sts 0x0067, r1  ; 0x800067 <i>
 238:   10 92 68 00     sts 0x0068, r1  ; 0x800068 <i+0x1>
 23c:   10 92 69 00     sts 0x0069, r1  ; 0x800069 <i+0x2>
 240:   10 92 6a 00     sts 0x006A, r1  ; 0x80006a <i+0x3>
 244:   80 91 66 00     lds r24, 0x0066 ; 0x800066 <__data_end>
 248:   8f 5f           subi    r24, 0xFF   ; 255
 24a:   c9 cf           rjmp    .-110       ; 0x1de <start_blink+0xe>

0000024c <handleCmd>:
 24c:   80 91 76 00     lds r24, 0x0076 ; 0x800076 <cmdState>
 250:   81 30           cpi r24, 0x01   ; 1
 252:   31 f5           brne    .+76        ; 0x2a0 <handleCmd+0x54>
 254:   e0 91 75 00     lds r30, 0x0075 ; 0x800075 <cmdReceived>
 258:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
 25a:   ee 0f           add r30, r30
 25c:   ff 1f           adc r31, r31
 25e:   ee 59           subi    r30, 0x9E   ; 158
 260:   ff 4f           sbci    r31, 0xFF   ; 255
 262:   01 90           ld  r0, Z+
 264:   f0 81           ld  r31, Z
 266:   e0 2d           mov r30, r0
 268:   09 95           icall
 26a:   90 93 61 00     sts 0x0061, r25 ; 0x800061 <__data_start+0x1>
 26e:   80 93 60 00     sts 0x0060, r24 ; 0x800060 <__data_start>
 272:   80 91 74 00     lds r24, 0x0074 ; 0x800074 <cmdRemaining>
 276:   81 11           cpse    r24, r1
 278:   0f c0           rjmp    .+30        ; 0x298 <handleCmd+0x4c>
 27a:   83 e0           ldi r24, 0x03   ; 3
 27c:   80 93 76 00     sts 0x0076, r24 ; 0x800076 <cmdState>
 280:   e0 91 60 00     lds r30, 0x0060 ; 0x800060 <__data_start>
 284:   f0 91 61 00     lds r31, 0x0061 ; 0x800061 <__data_start+0x1>
 288:   09 95           icall
 28a:   84 e1           ldi r24, 0x14   ; 20
 28c:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
 28e:   90 93 61 00     sts 0x0061, r25 ; 0x800061 <__data_start+0x1>
 292:   80 93 60 00     sts 0x0060, r24 ; 0x800060 <__data_start>
 296:   06 c0           rjmp    .+12        ; 0x2a4 <handleCmd+0x58>
 298:   82 e0           ldi r24, 0x02   ; 2
 29a:   80 93 76 00     sts 0x0076, r24 ; 0x800076 <cmdState>
 29e:   08 95           ret
 2a0:   83 30           cpi r24, 0x03   ; 3
 2a2:   71 f3           breq    .-36        ; 0x280 <handleCmd+0x34>
 2a4:   08 95           ret

000002a6 <main>:
 2a6:   18 ba           out 0x18, r1    ; 24
 2a8:   8a e1           ldi r24, 0x1A   ; 26
 2aa:   87 bb           out 0x17, r24   ; 23
 2ac:   88 e5           ldi r24, 0x58   ; 88
 2ae:   8d b9           out 0x0d, r24   ; 13
 2b0:   80 e4           ldi r24, 0x40   ; 64
 2b2:   8e b9           out 0x0e, r24   ; 14
 2b4:   85 e2           ldi r24, 0x25   ; 37
 2b6:   8f b9           out 0x0f, r24   ; 15
 2b8:   78 94           sei
 2ba:   c4 9a           sbi 0x18, 4 ; 24
 2bc:   c7 df           rcall   .-114       ; 0x24c <handleCmd>
 2be:   88 df           rcall   .-240       ; 0x1d0 <start_blink>
 2c0:   fd cf           rjmp    .-6         ; 0x2bc <main+0x16>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are not running out of flash? Can you update with the non-working source? The output of the compiler when you compile the non-working source? Output of the `avr-dump`?

Comment: I am not sure anymore... but avrdude tells me he succeed to verify all bytes...
avr-gcc tells me no warning nor error (-Wall, -pdentic). Sorry for the typo, it's `avr--objdump`

Comment: Note: I also tried with several chips (all ATtiny25V though) and they all behave the same

Comment: Can you post non working code? For example. here I see that your code starts at 0x000 with no interrupt vector table, so if you are enabling interrupts then you likely will get unwanted behavior.

Comment: As soon as I've more time, I'll post it. 
But I've found another problem that might caused this one, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55440304/very-strange-gpio-behaviour-programming-attiny25v-with-avr-gcc-and-avrdude-via-a

Comment: indeed, there are no interrupt vector Oo (On previous versions I think I've seen many jmp instruction at start, I'll check this out)

Comment: I see "sei" instruction in the disassembly but there is no vector table. Not suprising code does not work

Comment: @AterLux Indeed, that's a good point. I am kind of in a rush right now (and to the end of the week) so I can't go back on this code, but I declared some interrupt functions. Now one could ask why gcc didn't set it up Oo