# Very strange gpio behaviour programming ATtiny25v with avr-gcc and avrdude via a raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, avr, avr-gcc, avrdude

I have an ATtiny25v connected to a raspberry pi thtough SPI.

I use avr-gcc to compile my code. Then I use avrdude to upload it.

But I encounter a very strange phenomena : the main function is not called, and instead, the first instructions of the first function have effects on gpio...

I have a led connected on portb4.

...I tried with several chip of the same model, and they all behave the same (excluding a buggy one)

...Can someone explain it ?

**NOTE :**
I omitted to detail it, but neither the compiler (with `-Wall -pedantic`) nor avrdude (with `-v -v`) gives any error.

both the kcuzner and the upstream version (linux_gpio patched http://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?47550 ) gives the same results. kcuzner using linuxspi programmer behaves also the same.

this :

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define B(b) (1 << b)

void ledT(){
   PORTB ^= B(PORTB4);
}

void led(uint8_t s){
   if(s)
      PORTB |= B(PORTB4);
   else {
      PORTB &= ~B(PORTB4);
   }
}

int main(){
   PORTB = 0;
   DDRB = 0;
   USISR = 0;
   USIDR = 0;
   while(1);
   //return 0;
}
```

...lights on the led on start.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define B(b) (1 << b)

void ledT(){
   PORTB ^= B(PORTB3);
}

void led(uint8_t s){
   if(s)
      PORTB |= B(PORTB4);
   else {
      PORTB &= ~B(PORTB4);
   }
}

int main(){
   PORTB = 0;
   DDRB = 0;
   USISR = 0;
   USIDR = 0;
   while(1);
   //return 0;
}
```

...Keeps the led off

and this one :

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define B(b) (1 << b)

void ledT(){
   PORTB ^= B(PORTB4);
   PORTB ^= B(PORTB4);
}

void led(uint8_t s){
   if(s)
      PORTB |= B(PORTB4);
   else {
      PORTB &= ~B(PORTB4);
   }
}

int main(){
   PORTB = 0;
   DDRB = 0;
   USISR = 0;
   USIDR = 0;
   while(1);
   //return 0;
}
```

...keeps also the led off.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define B(b) (1 << b)

void ledT(){
   PORTB = PORTB | B(PORTB3);
   PORTB = PORTB | B(PORTB4);
}

void led(uint8_t s){
   if(s)
      PORTB |= B(PORTB4);
   else {
      PORTB &= ~B(PORTB4);
   }
}

int main(){
   PORTB = 0;
   DDRB = 0;
   USISR = 0;
   USIDR = 0;
   while(1);
   //return 0;
}
```

...Lights the led on

Comment: Could you just turn on one LED before get to the while(1). You have to set DDR bit register to logical one on desired bit (where is your LED) to use it as output.

Comment: can you provide the disassembly (usually it is .lss file in "debug" dir, if you're using Atmel Studio). My suggestion you have MCU selected wrong.